# How to pronounce '0' in British English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, numbers

How can we pronounce the number "0" in British English? I mean: telephone numbers, room numbers etc.

Which form is correct and where (why)?

1. [o](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/o_2?q=o)
2. [oh](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oh#british-1-2-1) or *Total English Starter Students' book* at page 17

Do we use "nought" or "zero" in science in British English?

Comment: **WRITE** specifically? Why would you spell it out rather than just using the numeral?

Comment: I do not mean spell. I want to know which form to use. I have seen both forms.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. If someone tells me they're in room 307... I write "307"... I don't write three zero seven. Similarly, if someone's phone number is 292.555.2020 I use the numerals. Again, why are you trying to write it out rather than use numerals? Please give a specific example.

Comment: If my edit changed your question the wrong way, feel free to roll back.

Comment: In the book Total _English Starter Students book_ at page 17 is example 020.8922.7255 and oh-two etc. What is correct? Oh or o?

Comment: That example uses no letters. Neither are correct. `0` is correct (the numeral zero).

Comment: The problem is that you have two different questions... Your title is "pronounce" - you can't pronounce anything if it's written... but then you ask how to write it. Please [edit] your question to be more clear!

Comment: @Catija - I think the OP might be asking how to spell out the phonetic pronunciation. For example, _"This is flight three-niner-oh-niner, over."_

Comment: I'm not British, but I believe it depends on context.  In some cases "naught", in others "nil" and others "zero".  [More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English)

Comment: @Andrew I know they use _nil_ in sport, _zero_ is everywhere but I have never seen to use _naught_.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič  apparently it's used in rare cases to refer to the literal "0", please see my link.  They may also say "aught" in dates, as in "nineteen-aught-six", although that sounds like a dialect, thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UK English noun **nought** does mean **zero**. This is different from **naught**, which means **nothing**. In US English they are spelling variants of the same word, and **naught** is the more standard usage for both meanings.

When reading a number out loud many English speakers will say **o** (pronounced **owe**) as in the letter **O** when meaning the digit zero.

So: "room 702" is often said "Room Seven O(we) Two" while "Seven Zero Two" is also used.  I don't believe I've ever heard someone say "Seven Nought Two". Similarly **O(we)** is used when reading out phone numbers, though my preference is to use **zero** when stating my own phone number.

But I think I hear "dial zero for the operator" far more frequently than "dial O(we) for operator."

Comment: Worth noting that the 0 (zero) spoke as O (owe) thing is recent.  After all, when the phone company put letters together with certain keys, the letter O went on digit 6, and the digit 0 is by itself.  At the time, phone makers believed *no one would get them mixed up.*

Comment: I would say, though, that in US English we don't say "naught" very much at all; I can't remember when I last heard someone call it "a naught".  It's pretty much always **zero** or **oh**.